# Are exponents unary operations?

Tags: terminology

I was looking at the list of "unary operators" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation, and I found that it does not include exponents, e.g., $4^2$. Are exponents not considered unary operators because technically something like $4^2 = 4 * 4$, which is a binary operation?

Comment: $f(x) = 4^x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ are considered unary operators.  As is any single value real function.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2$ is and $4^x$ are both unary operations.  And the article you cited states "An example is the function f : A → A"

So all single value real functions are unary operators.  If the article didn't mention exponents or power functions specifically it's only because it didn't consider them worth mentioning.

Comment: A function such as $f(x, n) = x^n$ would *not* be a unary operation, right? Because it takes in 2 arguments?